# Signals and slots in PySide - defining slot in class

Tags: python, signals-slots, pyside

I'm new to Qt and PySide and try to get a feeling for signals and slots in PySide.

While following the documentation of [Signals and Slots in PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide), I tried to transfer some code to be used in my class.

The following code creates a DoubleSpinBox. When changing the value I expect the value to be printed by both functions `value_changed_func` and `value_changed_class`, but only `value_changed_func` gets called.

```
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtGui

@QtCore.Slot(float)
def value_changed_func(value):
    print "Event func:"
    print value

class MainController(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._ui = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox(parent)

        self._ui.valueChanged.connect(self.value_changed_class)
        self._ui.valueChanged.connect(value_changed_func)

    @QtCore.Slot(float)
    def value_changed_class(self, value):
        print "Event class:"
        print value


app = QtGui.QApplication([])

main_window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
MainController(main_window)
main_window.show()

app.exec_()
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get `value_changed_class` to be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call the parent constructor:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    super(MainController, self).__init__(parent)
    ...
```